# strstr works only if my substring is at the end of string

Tags: c, strstr

I've encountered a couple of problems with the program that i'm writing now.

1. strstr outputs my substring only if it's at the end of my string [image]
2. it also outputs some trash characters after that [image]
3. I've had problems with "const char *haystack" and then adding input to it, so i did it with fgets and getchar loop
4. somewhere along the way it worked with a substring that was not only at the end, but then i outputted substring and the rest of the string ater that

here is my main:

```
int main() {
    char    haystack[250],
            needle[20];

    int     currentCharacter,
            i=0;

    fgets(needle,sizeof(needle),stdin); //getting my substring here (needle)

    while((currentCharacter=getchar())!=EOF) //getting my string here (haystack)

    {
        haystack[i]=currentCharacter;
        i++;
    }

    wordInString(haystack,needle);

    return(0);
}
```

and my function:

```
int wordInString(const char *str, const char * wd)
{
    char *ret;
    ret = strstr(str,wd);

    printf("The substring is: %s\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a terminating '\0' missing in haystack which will cause you all kinds of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You read one string with `fgets()` and the other with `getchar()` upto the end of file.  There is a trailing `'\n'` at the end of both strings, Hence `strstr()` can only match the substring if it is at the end of the main string.
Furthermore, you do not store a final `'\0'` at the end of `haystack`.  You must do this because `haystack` is a local array (automatic storage), and as such is not initialized implicitly.

You can correct the problem this way:

```
//getting my substring here (needle)
if (!fgets(needle, sizeof(needle), stdin)) {
    // unexpected EOF, exit
    exit(1);
}
needle[strcspn(needle, "\n")] = '\0';

//getting my string here (haystack)
if (!fgets(haystack, sizeof(haystack), stdin)) {
    // unexpected EOF, exit
    exit(1);
}
haystack[strcspn(haystack, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Comment: 1+ for using `strcspn()` :-)

Comment: Limiting the read-loop to not overflow the `haystack` would also be nice ... ;-)

Comment: I see it, and i entirely agree with the needle, since i want it limited to 1 line only, but when it comes to haystack - I'd like it to be more than 1 line. With that in mind, can i somehow do it, so that i don't need to define the haystack a [250] element array, and it woud count the elements as i end inputting? But then another problem would occur, since i wouldn't have \n in my needle, but i would have it in haystack - ergo it wouldn't match if the needle would be divided in 2 lines in my haystack.

Comment: You could translate neelines to spaces as you read the rest of stdin into the haystack buffer.