# strstr() always returns null

Tags: c, string, fgets, strstr

I'm working on program where I would like to find a match in a string. I am using the `strstr()` function to get the job done, but it has a weird behaviour.
I am using `fgets()` to read the string and then using `strstr()` to find a match, but it always returns null if the string is not the exact same as the match.

For example:

```
>string to search match in : This is testing environment
>match  : test
>returns : (null)

>string to search match in : test
>match  : test
>returns : test
```

Why does it behave this way and can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: How are you calling `strstr`? Can we see some code?

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are aware that "strings" read via `fgets()` typically contain the trailing new-line used to enter them?

Comment: Probably a duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34048907/694576

Comment: You got two down-votes on this relatively quickly (neither from me). For future reference, if you write in proper English, put in appropriate punctuation etc. (which I have now fixed for you), your question may be better received and more easily understood by those from whom you are seeking help.

Comment: See the following for many alternatives  [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach

```
char *p = strchr( match, '\n' );
if ( p ) *p = '\0';

p = strstr( source, match );
```

Comment: Or just do `match[strcspn(match, "\n\r")] = '\0';` to cut off any sort of trailing new-line sequence.

Comment: Since the newline will always be at the end, and the usual case is that it will be there (the newline not being there is the exceptional case) why not use `strrchr`? Or simply check the last character? :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  Why to search the last occurence of the new line character instead of to search the first occurence?:)

Comment: Because `fgets` will only place one newline in the string, and it will always be last if it's there. No need to search through the whole string when you know where it will be (if it's there).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg And what? How are you going to find the first occurence of the character using strrchr specifying the address of the string?

Comment: There is no difference between `strchr` and `strrchr` if there is at most 1 occurrence of the character.

Comment: @Kevin Actually there is a difference. strchr is more efficient than strrcht.:)